# Counterpart of pnorm of R in Winbugs

Tags: r, winbugs

I use `pnorm`in R for standard normal distribution. I am wondering what code I could use to do so in Winbugs because I will use the Bayesian probit.

For example I calculate p = Phi(Xbeta) as pnorm(Xbeta).

My question is how I could do this in Winbugs.

Answer (score 1):

Help --> User Manual --> Model Specification --> Logical nodes says what you want is `phi(Xbeta)`.
Though perhaps its description as "standard normal cdf" wasn't clear?

> "cdf" stands for "cumulative density function".

It also says there that you can use `probit(x) <- y` instead of `x <- phi(y)`.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. I actually wish to calculate p = phi((Xbeta)/2*sigmasquared), where 1/2sigma-squared is the scale parameter. In this case, am I right to think that I need to use probit(p) = (Xbeta)/2*sigma.squared)???

Comment: cumulative *distribution* function. :)